# Rails make model methods appear as attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model connecting to a Postgres db.

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord

  def say_id
    "#{name} has id: #{id}"
  end

end
```

I have some attributes id,name,email as well as the method above: say_id that can be accessed via:

```
person = Person.new
person.id => 1
person.say_id  => "John has id: 1"
```

I would like to have the method 'say_id' listed as an attribute as well, now when running person.attributes, I'm only seeing: id, name, email

How can I have my method included as a listable information in full, as with person.attributes but which will include my method? A usecase would be for lazily just laying out all these fields in a table of the Person-object.

Comment: While you can do this using some metaprogramming magic, you do not want to do that, because it will potentially break all of _Rails_. Attributes are attributes, methods are methods, there is zero sense to mix them up.

Comment: "How can I have my method included as an attribute in full?" - but it's not an attribute. You can't write it, for example.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin thanks for your answer.. Is there a way to make it more visible when looking at the model, eg listing all readable information of a model object?

Comment: Like `def methods_and_attributes; methods(false) + attributes; end`?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I don't agree. Methods are methods, instance variables are instance variables and attributes are an abstraction we invented when we made getters/setters that make ivars available to the outside. Its hard to draw a hard fast line on which is which.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev neither can you with a read-only attribute. Yet we still call it an attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rails 5+ you can use the [attributes api](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html) to create attributes that are not backed by a database column:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :foo
end
```

```
irb(main):002:0> Person.new.attributes
=> {"id"=>nil, "email"=>nil, "name"=>nil, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil, "foo"=>nil}
```

Unlike if you used `attr_accessor` these actually behave very much like database backed attributes.

You can then override the getter method if you wanted to:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :foo

  def foo
    "foo is #{super}"
  end
end
```

```
irb(main):005:0> Person.new(foo: 'bar').foo
=> "foo is bar"
```

But for whatever you're doing its still not the right answer. You can get a list of the methods of an class by calling `.instance_methods` on a class:

```
irb(main):007:0> Person.instance_methods(false)
=> [:foo]
```

Passing `false` filters out inherited methods.